# Detect random strings

Tags: php, regex

I am building a string to detect whether filename makes sense or if they are completely random with PHP. I'm using regular expressions.

A valid filename = `sample-image-25.jpg`

A random filename = `46347sdga467234626.jpg`

I want to check if the filename makes sense or not, if not, I want to alert the user to fix the filename before continuing.

Any help?

Comment: Can you give us some rules that would help differentiate between "valid" and "random"?

Comment: if the file names are say ascii there is no reason other then a format requirement that both of those aren't valid so as we can only check for a said format without a format you can't check for one

Comment: There's no approach that could reliably do this. Why exactly aren't random fienames ok?

Comment: `sample-image-25.jpg` can also be the result of a random file name generator.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "makes sense"? Regular expressions could help you determine if the filename was a series of word characters separated by dashes with a number on the end (as the example you give), but could not determine whether the words were legitimate words. (For example, flizzle-wooble-99.jpg would be fine as the "words" contain only characters normally found in words. For that matter, zzzz-qq-23.jpg would also be fine as z and q are normally found in words.) To determine whether the strings of characters were legitimate words, you would need to use a dictionary of valid words.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure that's possible because I'm not sure it's possible to define "random" in a way the computer will understand sufficiently well.

"umiarkowany" looks random, but it's a perfectly valid word I pulled off the Polish Wikipedia page for South Korea.

My advice is to think more deeply about why this design detail is important, and look for a more feasible solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need way to much work on that. You should make an huge array of most-used-word (like a dictionary) and check if most of the work inside the file (maybe separated by `-` or `_`) are there and it will have huge bugs.

Basically you will need of

- `explode()`
- `implode()`
- `array_search()` or `in_array()`

Take the string and look for a piece glue like "_" or "-" with `preg_match()`; if there are some, explode the string into an array and compare that array with the dictionary array.

Or, since almost every words has alternate vowel and consonants you could make an huge script that checks whatever most of the words inside the file name are considered "not-random" generated. But the problem will be the same: why do you need of that? Check for a more flexible solution.

Notice:
Consider that even a `simple-and-friendly-file.png` could be the result of a string generator.

Good luck with that.